# schunk_svh_driver:a finger has a hardware failure

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I install package schunk_svh_driver calling:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-schunk-svh-driver
```

but the THUMB's schunk 5 finger hand that I'm using has a hardware failure and so I want disable_flags (1 and 2) calling:

```
roslaunch schunk_svh_driver svh_controller.launch disable_flags:=[true true false false false false false false false]
```

but I get the error:

```
roslaunch: error: The following input files do not exist: false].
```

How I can disable the thumb?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207697/schunk_svh_driver:a-finger-has-a-hardware-failure/) by [Alba](https://answers.ros.org/users/22228/alba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2015-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2015-04-23**:
it seemed that your command needs comma like [true, true, ...
have you tried that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
on this site http://wiki.ros.org/schunk_svh_driver it tells something about a  svh.yaml file, have you done that ?

A finger is broken, can i still use the rest of the finger?

YES! You can disable the finger by editing the "etc/svh.yaml" file or by copying it and then providing it via launch argument. Change the "disable_flags" value of the finger you want to disable to true and it will not be used during execution. However all calls to this finger will be answered in the most positive way possible (i.e. it will register as enabled and homed)

---

Originally posted by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) with karma: 406 on 2015-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alba](https://answers.ros.org/users/22228/alba/) on 2015-04-24**:
thanks a lot!